# Quartz´s configuration with Oracle

Tags: oracle, quartz.net

How to configure the Quartz's configuration file to work with Oracle. I'm using Quartz.NET 2.0, Oracle 10G and Visual Studio 2010.

I have implemented Quartz 1.0.3 in a project. I have to update the Quartz project to version 2.0, in order to do that i created a Job in a test project and added references to the Quartz's Dlls. The weird is that the Job is working well without install the Quartz service... how is this possible???

Comment: Please try to describe what kind of job do you want to schedule with Quartz?

Comment: I have several jobs using Quartz version 1.0.3 and i'm making the migration to version 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run Oracle table creation scripts contained in quartz.net package. I
   think the script is under Quartz\database\tables\tables_oracle.sql
2. Modify Quartz.Config

   ```
   quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = your table prefix , I think default is QRTZ_

   quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS

   quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionString = your connection string

   quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider = OracleClient-20
   ```

I think you will be good to go, if you are running quartz as embedded you can number 2 in ypur code.

For more see [this tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_9.html)

Comment: Is it the same in version 2.0 that 1.0.3 ?

Comment: Nothing have changed for quartz.net config configuration settings.

Comment: I have implemented Quartz 1.0.3 in a project. I have to update the Quartz project to version 2.0, in order to do that i created a Job in a test project and added references to the Quartz's Dlls. The weird is that the Job is working well without install the Quartz service...how is this possible???

Comment: What you need to do is to modify your job file. Job configuration on quartz 2.0 are different. For more [see](http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2011/03/new-in-quartznet-20new-job-file-format.html)

Comment: I have modified the implementation of the jobs.

Comment: I have these errors: Could not parse property 'class' into correct data type: No property 'Class'

JobStore type 'Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX' props could not be configured.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle database has many options for running scheduled jobs. So maybe you do not really need Quartz for what you want to do. You can use the older [DBMS_JOB](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_job.html) package or the newer and more sophisticated  [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Scheduler10g.php) is also available in 10g.